# How to change a custom Button Attribute on Click in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using the package com.github.fornewid:neumorphism:0.3.0, to implement a Neomorphic button.
The package has an attribute to neumorph_shapeType(pressed) which I want to change to the value "flat" in the event of a button click.
Can somebody share the related tutorial or reference sites I can use to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the code :https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism
and the tutorial from the author's article : https://fornewid.medium.com/neumorphism-in-android-9cf15e2122dc

Also, do no forget to review the issues and PR in the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism/issues